# Angular installation issues

Tags: angular

[cli screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBQLp.png)

I have installed node 13.90 in my system, and I further want to install Angular 4. I am using the command `npm install -g @angular/cli`. But I am unable to do so. Need some suggestions.

PS: I use windows 10 64 bit 4 gb ram

Comment: Please do not post code or error logs as image (as they can't be searched).
It seems like the Cli is already installed, have you tried using it or using the --force option?

Answer (score 0):

It's saying files already exist and it does not feel like overwriting those files. If you use what is suggested in the error message it should ignore this by using `--force`.

```sh
npm install -g @angular/cli --force
```

Comment: Is that sarcastic? If you've already tried that please include it in your question.

Comment: i used --force. The installation process was completed.

Comment: Nice! Could you mark this as an answer? Might help out more people in the future. You can do this by clicking the 'V' to the left.